# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, 2d, bufferedimage

I am developing a 2D RPG game. This morning when I ran it, I got the error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at com.hosfordryan.tileRPG.gfx.ImageLoader.load(ImageLoader.java:12)
at com.hosfordryan.tileRPG.Game.init(Game.java:40)
at com.hosfordryan.tileRPG.Game.run(Game.java:68)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The code of the init method is as following:

```
public void init(){
    ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
    spriteSheet = loader.load("/spritesheet.png");

    SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(spriteSheet);
    im = new ImageManager(ss);
    player = new Player(9*16*Game.SCALE,9*16*Game.SCALE,im);

    BufferedImage limage = loader.load("res/level11.png");
    //BufferedImage l2mage = loader.load("/Level12.png");
    //l2 = new Level(l2mage);
    l1 = new Level(limage);
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyManager());
}
```

The image loader class:

public class ImageLoader {

```
public BufferedImage load(String path){
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

And the run method is just calling the init method.
I am not sure why this is happening today. It wasn't happening yesterday. Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Do you really have a file in the root directory called "spritesheet.png"?

Comment: if you need current dir remove back slash `spriteSheet = loader.load("spritesheet.png");` loader can't find file

Comment: It is loading the spritesheet. I put a println right after it, and it prints. Although it does not get to the println after the loading of level1.png

Comment: Never mind... I am an idiot... had something misspelled